# How to parse or slice JSON string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a result from api call response using Python.

Converted the response to JSON string using json.dumps(response,indent=2) and the result is like below. How to call or get the value of first id number from below the json string.

```
{
  "policies": [
    {
      "id": 1119732,
      "incident_preference": "PER_CONDITION_AND_TARGET",
      "name": "Alert 1",
      "created_at": 1605003072469,
      "updated_at": 1673391349002
    },
    {
      "id": 1133740,
      "incident_preference": "PER_CONDITION",
      "name": "Alert 2",
      "created_at": 1605780951866,
      "updated_at": 1673391348520
    },
    {
      "id": 1136308,
      "incident_preference": "PER_CONDITION",
      "name": "Alert 3",
      "created_at": 1605886254921,
      "updated_at": 1673391349028
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you had a dictionary, is there any compelling reason to cast it to a string at this point if what you want is to access it as data? I.E. `response[0]["id"]` otherwise `json.loads()` will undo you `dumps()`

Comment: Amazing.. I was breaking my head. response[0]["id"] worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of what you can do to get the id's of each policy.

```
import json

# starting value is json string
json_string = '''{"policies": [{"id": 1119732,"incident_preference": "PER_CONDITION_AND_TARGET"}, {"id":1133740,"incident_preference":"PER_CONDITION","name":"Alert 2","created_at":1605780951866,"updated_at":1673391348520}, {"id":1136308,"incident_preference":"PER_CONDITION","name":"Alert 3","created_at":1605886254921,"updated_at":1673391349028}]}'''

# use json.loads to make JSON string into dict obj
json_dict_obj = json.loads(json_string)

# assign policies list to var
policies = json_dict_obj.get('policies')

# iterate over policies list and print id value
for policy in policies:
  print(policy.get('id'))
```